# How do I stop psql from displaying executed SQL?

Tags: psql, log

When I execute SQL, I see the query echoed back at me.

```
=# \d
LOG:  statement: SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  c.relname as "Name",
  CASE c.relkind WHEN 'r' THEN 'table' WHEN 'v' THEN 'view' WHEN 'm' THEN
  [... LOT OF STUFF CUT]
                   List of relations
 Schema |          Name          |   Type   |  Owner   
--------+------------------------+----------+----------
```

All queries get echoed too,

```
=# SELECT * FROM ( VALUES (1) ) AS t(x);
LOG:  statement: SELECT * FROM ( VALUES (1) ) AS t(x);
 x 
---
 1
(1 row)
```

How do I disable this feature? I've tried lots of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two methods that can cause the query to be echoed.

- With `psql -E` (or `\set ECHO_HIDDEN`) the queries that `psql` executes with client commands `\command` are echoed back at you. You can see if this is set by running `\set` and looking for `ECHO_HIDDEN`. If set, you should try running without `-E`, not setting the option yourself, and making sure it's not set in the [`~/.psqlrc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#id-1.9.4.18.10). If set the query will look like this above every client command

  ```
  ********* QUERY **********
  query
  **************************
  ```
- If you see `LOG:  statement:`, **you may have awkward configurations on the server**, like

  ```
  client_min_messages='LOG';
  log_statement='all';
  ```

  See the docs on [*Error Reporting and Logging*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html) for more information. You should check,

  ```
  SHOW client_min_messages;
  SHOW log_statement;
  ```

  If set, this is an indicator that someone opened up the server-configuration file and wanted more logging but didn't know what they were doing.

In your case you have `LOG:  statement:` so check the server settings.

Comment: I had `log_min_duration_statement` set to '0' with basically the same result.